# Merge [titanium-mobile] and [titanium] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Titanium-mobile was created in the time there also was titanium-desktop. However, this product was long ago removed and now the only titanum product is the mobile sdk.

To me this sounds the [titanium-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/titanium-mobile) tag should be merged into the [titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/titanium) tag to prevent confusion and duplicate tags.